# Procedimentos após erros devem ficar nos serviços/validações ou no controller?

Tags: validação, controller, services

Num backend que possui funções de validação separadas para verificar a validade dos dados, caso esses dados sejam inválidos o procedimento (retornar um 400 ou imprimir algo na tela, por exemplo) deve ocorrer nessa parte de validação ou é uma tarefa para o controller?

No frontend onde tenho uma parte que cuida das requisições ao servidor (serviços), quando é recebido um erro de uma dessas requisições, notificar o usuário é tarefa do próprio serviço ou do controlador?

De quem é a responsabilidade?

exemplo simples com php (a pergunta não é focada em nenhuma linguagem, apenas para exemplo)

main.php:

```
//Forma 1
isValidPassword("123", "321");

//Forma 2
isValidPassword("123", "321") or die("senhas diferente");
```

validation.php:

```
//Forma 1
function isValidPassword($password, $confirm) {
    $password === $confirm or die("senhas diferente");
}

//Forma 2
function isValidPassword($password, $confirm) {
    return $password === $confirm;
}
```

No frontend a ideia é a mesma, executar um `alert()` no controller ou na função de validação?

Comment: Guilherme, não consegui entender muito bem sua pergunta. Mas pelo que eu entendi, todas as funções de validação como campo requerido, valor máximo e minimo, comparar campos, devem ser feito no front-end, devido a velocidade e envio desnecessário ao seu backend, seu backend tem que ser responsavel por todo o processamento da sua regra de negocio.

Comment: Não concordo com o que disse, isso deve ser feito tanto no front (por questão de ux e não performance) como no back, por questão de segurança, alguém poderia facilmente criar requisições com dados inválidos ou mal formatados e o back não pode salvar esses dados

Comment: Voce pode aplicar seguranca no seu backend, que apenas seu front consiga comunicacao com ele, existe diversas maneiras fazer isso. Porem concordo com voce referente a nao deixar salvar dados invalidos, mas se uma seguranca bem construida dificilmente uma requisicao pode ser passada de forma indesejada

Comment: Desculpe, mas o @PauloAlexandre está completamente equivocado. Não há como saber de onde vem a requisição, isso é facilmente forjado. Qualquer usuário poderá enviar qualquer valor. Você mesmo pode testar isto usando o cURL, por exemplo, assim poderá enviar qualquer informação. A analise do conteúdo, se está de acordo com o que espera, deve ser feito no servidor. Claro, que como mencionado, pode também fazer no lado do cliente, apenas por questões de otimizar o experiencia do usuário.

Comment: o que eu digo @lnkeliz se voce coloca uma autenticação, nao tem como ser chamado pelo cURL, só se a pessoa souber como se autentica no seu servidor.

Comment: @PauloAlexandre E como vai funcionar a autenticação? O que irá impedir um monitoramento de tráfego e saber como a autenticação é feita? Não existe essa mágica, se você está recebendo um conteúdo arbitrário de outras pessoas. A única forma de "autenticação" seria ter um hardware seguro que também contenha uma chave criptográfica não-extraível. Assim o usuário enviaria o conteúdo para tal dispositivo e ele iria assinar, se correto. Assim o servidor aceitaria, assinaturas válidas, isso é similar ao "Challenge" do FIDO U2F. Entretanto, isso é puramente inviável.

Comment: Falo em .NET que é onde eu tenho mais experiencia, voce poderia colocar autenticação em toda sua api, com o OAUTH 2.0, como funciona no GOOGLE, voce so consegue chamar as APIs caso voce tenha um TOKEN valido, que é adquirido quando voce faz um rest com seu usuario, senha e api que voce deseja acessar

Comment: @PauloAlexandre isso continua inútil. O OAUTH apenas diz se alguém está ou não autorizado a fazer a requisição. Entretanto, uma vez que possui uma sessão válida, um token válido, voce pode enviar qualquer requisição. Isso é, não há qualquer filtro do que pode ou não ser enviado, o servidor continua sendo responsável por restringir o que é válido ou não, assim o uso de "restrições no front-end" é inútil, no aspecto de segurança.

Comment: @Guilherme Costamilam, além disso não use `$password === $confirm`, isso é vulnerável a timing attack. O PHP tem o hash_equals, que compara de maneira segura, e melhor ainda, tem o password_hash.

Comment: Obrigado @Inkeliz, o código é bem básico, só de exemplo mesmo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ponto de Vista da Qualidade do Código

Do ponto de vista da qualidade do código, ele deveria utilizar a forma 2. A razão decorre de duas perguntas que eu, programador que herdou o seu código para manutenção, por exemplo, me farei considerando somente o nome da sua função (sem precisar olhar o código dela):

1. O que eu espero que a sua função `isValidPassord` faça?
2. O que eu espero que a sua função `isValidPassord` retorne?

Bom, pelo nome dela, eu espero que ela verifique se a senha é válida e retorne verdadeiro caso seja válida e falso caso contrário. Na forma 1, a função faz mais do que isso. Ela encerra o script caso a senha não seja válida, e isso pode ser um comportamento considerado inesperado por alguém "lendo" o código.

Tá errado? Não. É algo desejável? Também não, porque esse tipo de coisa (principalmente acumulada em grandes projetos) vai dificultar o trabalho e a saída de férias de colegas ou de você mesmo (a experiência demonstra isso, meu caro).

### Ponto de Vista da UX

Do ponto de vista da UX as validações devem ser feitas no FrontEnd sempre que possível. A razão é porque assim um erro do usuário pode ser comunicado muito mais rapidamente, sem ele precisar esperar a comunicação com o servidor. Não costuma ser o caso da validação de senha ou de outras coisas que requerem consulta a um banco de dados, mas é o caso de validações de CPF, formatos de dados, etc. Veja que eu disse "sempre que *possível*".

### Ponto de Vista da Arquitetura

É uma boa ideia separar a validação de qualquer ação diferente dela (regras do negócio, por exemplo) porque você torna os serviços (e eu estou usando de forma geral, a validação também pode ser um serviço) mais atomizados e reutilizáveis. A atomização, aliás, facilita os testes e a garantia de que uma alteração numa função X que use a validação V não vai quebrar essa uma outra função Y que eventualmente também use essa validação V.

Comment: Se alterasse o nome da função para algo mais claro, teria algum problema em relação a qualidade de código? Tem alguma sugestão de nome que não seja muito grande?

Comment: No seu exemplo você alteraria a função para que? Que tal `isValidPasswordOrCommunicateUser`? Não soa nada ok né? Talvez algo como `ForcePasswordCheck` ficasse melhor, mas veja que ao fazer isso você só deixa mais visível o baixo reuso da sua função. De novo: tá errado? Não tá. É bom? A minha experiência diz que não, mas realmente é um tanto discutível... Com o tempo vc melhora o seu entendimento a respeito. :)

Comment: Esqueci de dar a recompensa, mals