# Como validar os dados de forma segura no frontend?

Tags: http, segurança, http-request

Segundo [esse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316861/procedimentos-ap%C3%B3s-erros-devem-ficar-nos-servi%C3%A7os-valida%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ou-no-controller#comment642897_316861) de @PauloAlexandre, seria possível validar os dados apenas no front, de forma que o back só receba os dados prontos

Sei que é possível limitar, por meio de CORS, a origem da requisição entre outras coisas

Mas realmente é possível fazer o que citei a cima? Como?

Comment: Isso quebra a regra número 1 da web: nunca confie nos dados do seu cliente.

Comment: E se o atacante fizer um XSS no seu site e efetuar a requisição do seu próprio domínio? Em um caso ideal, que você feche toda e qualquer brecha de segurança, quem sabe, você até poderia confiar, mas quem te garantirá que você fechou todas elas? Eu acho bem menos trabalho fazer a validação no backend também - e com certeza bem mais barato.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss poderia dar uma resposta aprofundando isso tudo?

Comment: Não, jamais valide os dados apenas no front. O proprio browser te da possibilidade de editar um request, portanto sua limitação no CORS não vale nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca deve acreditar numa informação do cliente, esta é a regra básica.

Você pode incluir filtros e validações no lado do cliente, afim de proporcionar uma melhor experiencia de uso, já que os erros serão imediatos, não tendo que aguardar a resposta do servidor.

Mas, obrigatoriamente deverá fazer a mesma verificação no servidor.

---

Não há como saber a "origem de requisição", esquece. O CORS apenas afeta o contexto do navegador, ele não é a única forma de comunicação com sites. O CORS é feito para que **o navegador**, honesto, não permita conexões entre sites.

Você pode simplesmente "burlar isso" usando o [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html), por exemplo:

```
curl ^
-H "Origin: seusite.com" ^
-H "Referer: https://seusite.com" ^
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.54" ^
-d "nome=12345&email=xxxxxx&senha=000" ^
-X POST ^
https://seusite.com/registrar
```

Note que estamos fingindo estar no `seusite.com` acrescentando os cabeçalhos de `Origin` e `Referer`, o que irá enganar qualquer validação de "origem". Além disso, acrescentamos o `User-Agent` para fingir ser um navegador comum. Depois disso enviamos qualquer informação arbitrária, como: `nome=12345&email=xxxxxx&senha=000`, se o filtro for somente no cliente, nós ignoramos completamente.

Comment: Desse modo, também é possível também enviar um ip falso?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, depende. [Se você acreditar nos cabeçalhos, sim.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222285/porque-não-é-bom-usar-essa-função-e-como-eu-identifico-o-ip-do-usuário-então/222302#222302). Mas, tirando essa situação, o TCP (e consequentemente o HTTP) não tem como falsificar o IP devido ao handshake, o máximo que pode é usar proxies, o que não é uma "falsificação" em si. Mas, se por algum motivo, estiver usando UDP, você poderá ter problemas com falsificação de IP.

Answer (score 0):

**Não**! Do ponto de vista de um atacante, não existe "validação segura no front-end", ela simplesmente será ignorada.

---

Por mais que você limite a origem do request(CORS), é extremamente simples editar o conteúdo de um request utilizando ferramentas como BurpSuite ou até mesmo através do próprio browser. Ou seja, é possível enviar um request válido contendo um payload malicioso.